# How to force creating an extended partition in before the last primary partition in kickstart?

Tags: centos7, kickstart, anaconda, partition-table

I am searching for a way to write a kickstart partition section where I can control precisely which partitions are primary, and which partitions are secondary partitions in a extended partition.

I don't want to use LVM, and I want to create this partition table :

[image]

On this screen, the sizes are not important, it was just a try to see if I really can do this kind of partition table.

I want the last partition (sdb4) to be physically at the end of the drive, and for that, I need to put sdb5 and sdb6 in an extended partition.

The problem is that the kickstart file parse the instructions sequentially, and the last partition is the last part instruction. But the problem is that kickstart will declare everything as primary and auto-create an extended partition automatically.

The problem is that I don't seems to find a way to do what I want.

Is that even possible ?

Comment: You are booting with EFI? You should be using GPT partition table. There is no such thing as a logical or extended partition.

Comment: Sadly I am using old legacy bios 

Comment: What is the EFI partiton for, then? If you legacy boot then you don't need it.

Comment: It’s just an example, I just need this kind of partition table, the filesystem, size and kind is meaningless in this screen